# kdev-python with python 3 support

Tags: python, kdevelop

I just discovered kdevelop and the kdev-python plugin, it is just awesome, to say the least.

However, on my system (Kubuntu 15.04), when I install kdev-python via apt-get it seems that there is no support for python 3 yet, as I can't execute a python 3 script.

I've read on the Internet that the support for python 3 has been done, but what is the package I have to install? Or is it only available from source? On Launchpad I've read that kdev-python3 is a missing package for the moment, but maybe there is another way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download  version 1.6.1 from  [download.kde.org/](http://download.kde.org/stable/kdevelop/kdev-python/1.6.1/src/kdev-python-v1.6.1-py3.tar.xz.mirrorlist) which supports python3, to install unzip then cd to `kdev-python-v1.6.1-py3` and run:

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
make install
```

one cavaet is that seemingly you can only have either the python2 or python3 version installed at any one time according to a post [here](http://scummos.blogspot.ie/2014/03/kdevelop-python-for-python-3-first.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this after installing kdelibs5-dev and kdevplatform-dev. But cmake tells me that it wants the Python libs version 3.4 exactly and that I have version 3.4.3, and it refuses them. Is there anything that I can do to continue the compilation (like a cmake option) or I have to install exactly Python 3.4? I am not familiar with these kind of issues.

Comment: OK, I compiled the newest version of cmake and this problem disappeared. But now, I have a problem with kdevplatform, some required header is not on a machine, there should be some version mismatch between the versions required.

Comment: cmake cannot find the kdevplatform's header kdevplatform/language/interfaces/iproblem.h, I really don't have it in my /usr/include directory.